# How do I delete the django cache database table?

Tags: django, django-models, django-cache

I have been using django's database caching as shown here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/cache/#database-caching

Recently I have migrated to redis caching, but I still have the cache table in my database from the command `python manage.py createcachetable`.

How can I safely delete this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a custom empty migration with

`./manage.py makemigrations --empty myApp`

And then add raw SQL to drop the table.

```
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ("myApp", "latest_migration"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cache_table_name;"),
    ]
```